# How to add fadeIn effect or transition to scrolltop menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to make a very good transition effect in the scrolltop menu. Now, when I scroll down, the animation is not involved, I tried to do it myself, but it was unsuccessful. Please help me out to do this.

Here is my code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('nav').addClass("scroll-down").fadeIn('fast');
    $('.header-container').hide();
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass("scroll-down").fadeIn('fast');
    $('.header-container').show();
  }
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed!important;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  z-index: 9999;
}

nav.scroll-down {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-common">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="first active"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="produkcziya">Продукция</a></li>
        <li><a href="o-kompanii">О компании</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="infoblok" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Инфоблок</a>
          <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
            <li class="first"><a href="infoblok/novosti">Новости</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="infoblok/stati">Статьи</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="oplata-i-dostavka">Оплата и доставка</a></li>
        <li><a href="kontaktyi">Контакты</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="postavshhikam">Поставщикам</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The transition needs to be on the nav. You're saying what you want to transition, and in this case everything. The second class you need to say what you want to transition. I'm not sure if this works by adding a class selector dynamically.

Comment: @Gezzasa transition effect, I talking about FadeIn effect, when user scrolls down the page.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, when scrolling down the NAV  Fades out and scrolling up fades it in? Either way, I don't think you're using the transitions correctly. Posting an answer now.

Comment: Can you please ensure that your code snippet is actually working? All I see is an unstyled nav with no possibility of scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I haven't tested this but this is what I always do

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
     $('nav').fadeIn(300, function() { 
      $(this).addClass("scroll-down");
      $('.header-container').hide();
     });
   } else {
     $('nav').fadeOut(300, function() { 
       $(this).removeClass("scroll-down");
       $('.header-container').show();
     });
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to figure the jquery scrolling part out.

The transition needs to be on the `nav`. You're saying what you want to transition, and in this case everything. The second class you need to say what you want to transition.

https://jsfiddle.net/fwftvma7/3/

```
.example {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 2s ease-in; /* Safari */
  transition: top 2s ease-in;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.example.clicked {
  top: -50px;
}
```

You'll see my `.example` is what I want to transition and my `.example.clicked` is what I want it to transform to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script (replace the scroll top arrow image):

```js
var scrolltotop = {
  setting: {
    startline: 100,
    scrollto: 0,
    scrollduration: 1e3,
    fadeduration: [500, 100]
  },
  controlHTML: '<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40" />',
  controlattrs: {
    offsetx: 5,
    offsety: 5
  },
  anchorkeyword: "#top",
  state: {
    isvisible: !1,
    shouldvisible: !1
  },
  scrollup: function() {
    this.cssfixedsupport || this.$control.css({
      opacity: 0
    });
    var t = isNaN(this.setting.scrollto) ? this.setting.scrollto : parseInt(this.setting.scrollto);
    t = "string" == typeof t && 1 == jQuery("#" + t).length ? jQuery("#" + t).offset().top : 0, this.$body.animate({
      scrollTop: t
    }, this.setting.scrollduration)
  },
  keepfixed: function() {
    var t = jQuery(window),
      o = t.scrollLeft() + t.width() - this.$control.width() - this.controlattrs.offsetx,
      s = t.scrollTop() + t.height() - this.$control.height() - this.controlattrs.offsety;
    this.$control.css({
      left: o + "px",
      top: s + "px"
    })
  },
  togglecontrol: function() {
    var t = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    this.cssfixedsupport || this.keepfixed(), this.state.shouldvisible = t >= this.setting.startline ? !0 : !1, this.state.shouldvisible && !this.state.isvisible ? (this.$control.stop().animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, this.setting.fadeduration[0]), this.state.isvisible = !0) : 0 == this.state.shouldvisible && this.state.isvisible && (this.$control.stop().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, this.setting.fadeduration[1]), this.state.isvisible = !1)
  },
  init: function() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(t) {
      var o = scrolltotop,
        s = document.all;
      o.cssfixedsupport = !s || s && "CSS1Compat" == document.compatMode && window.XMLHttpRequest, o.$body = t(window.opera ? "CSS1Compat" == document.compatMode ? "html" : "body" : "html,body"), o.$control = t('<div id="topcontrol">' + o.controlHTML + "</div>").css({
        position: o.cssfixedsupport ? "fixed" : "absolute",
        bottom: o.controlattrs.offsety,
        right: o.controlattrs.offsetx,
        opacity: 0,
        cursor: "pointer"
      }).attr({
        title: "Scroll to Top"
      }).click(function() {
        return o.scrollup(), !1
      }).appendTo("body"), document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest && "" != o.$control.text() && o.$control.css({
        width: o.$control.width()
      }), o.togglecontrol(), t('a[href="' + o.anchorkeyword + '"]').click(function() {
        return o.scrollup(), !1
      }), t(window).bind("scroll resize", function(t) {
        o.togglecontrol()
      })
    })
  }
};
scrolltotop.init();
```

```css
.body {
  height:2000px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
Scroll bottom
</div>
```